# How to navigate from a library to app components

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, module, angular-routing

I have implemented my `login-component` as a `library` and the first thing shown in `myApp` is the `login` page.

However, I don't know how to navigate to `home` page after a successful login.
Does any one know how can I achieve it? Thank you.

Here is my `app-routing.module.ts`:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { PreloadAllModules, RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    loadChildren: () => import('login').then(m => m.LoginPageModule)
  },
 {
    path: 'home',
    loadChildren: () => import('./home/home.module').then(m => m.HomePageModule)
  },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { preloadingStrategy: PreloadAllModules })
  ],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you should use something similar as below (I didn't check it):

In your component class instantiate Router and after success login redirect to another address:

```
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

constructor(
  private route: Router,
) {}

// Your auth method
authUser(): void {
  ....

  if (authSuccess) {
    this.router.navigateByUrl('/home');
  }
  
}
```